# Jenkinsfile in repo different from the code

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

Goal: Have one Jenkinsfile for all jenkins jobs (around 100) - 'One file to rule them all'

What I've tried:

Create a jenkins job with 2 repo's:

1 - {GIT_URL_1} : repo where is the Jenkinsfile

2 - {GIT_URL_2} : repo with the code to build

Jenkinsfile

```
stage('Checkout'){
        when {
            not {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'master';
                    branch 'develop';
                    branch 'release'
                }
            }

        }
        steps { 
            // dir ('repo') {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'running'                                
                git "${GIT_URL_1}"
                checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [
                $class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: "${gitlabSourceBranch}"]],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false
                load 'Jenkinsfile'
            }
```

Erro message

> ERROR: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/app/myapp@script/Jenkinsfile not
>   found

If I swap the GIT_URL position - checkout first the repo then the jenkinsfile, I get the same error message

Comment: Have you considered loading the universal Jenkinsfile from the Pipeline Job interface instead?

Comment: Have a look at Shared Libraries: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: @MattSchuchard I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the directory before checkout the second repo.

```
steps { 
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins', state: 'running'
                dir ('repo') {                    
                git branch: "${gitlabSourceBranch}", credentialsId: 'ABCDEFG', url: "${gitlabSourceRepoURL}"
```

1 - Checkout the repo with the jenkinsfile

2 - jenkinfile change directory

3 - checkout the repo with the code to build

This solution lead to others minor problems like, changelog from the wrong repository (jenkinsfile repo) but I can deal with it.

Also is faster than create a shared library (which is the better solution)